# Prove $N(R^TR)=N(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose R is m by n with rank r and pivot columns first: (strang 4 ed. 3.3, problem 27)
>
> $$ R =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I & F \\
> 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> Prove that $R^{T}R$ has the same nullspace as $R$.
>
> $$
> R^{T}= 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I & 0 \\
> F & 0
> \end{bmatrix}
> \implies
> $$
>   $$
> R^{T}R = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I & F \\
> F & F^{2}
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

Here is where I am stuck- I know that for them to have the same null space means they have to have the same column space. That seems pretty easy with the first column of $R^{T}R$, but how do I show it with the second half of columns?

Answer (score 4):

Let $x\in \ker(R^TR)$ then we have $R^TRx=0$ so

$$0=\langle R^TRx,x\rangle=\langle Rx ,Rx\rangle=||Rx||^2\iff Rx=0\iff x\in\ker(R)$$
so we get

$$\ker(R^TR)\subset \ker(R)$$
and the other inclusion is trivial. Conclude.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with your notation. What do the brackets signify?

Comment: $\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product.